# Не работает css transitions

Tags: css3

есть css

```
    .score {
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
   .score-big {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
}
```

и есть js

```
 $('.score').addClass('score-big')
```

но почему-то scale применяется без анимации. а когда я через хром убираю и возвращаю scale, то анимация есть. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.score-big {
            -webkit-transform: scale(3);
            -moz-transform: scale(3);
            -o-transform: scale(3);
            -ms-transform: scale(3);
            transform: scale(3);
        }
```

может нужно использовать вендорные преффиксы

http://jsfiddle.net/6y3x7/

Comment: нет, через средства разработчика же я изменяю любое значение, и оно изменяется с анимацией. и у меня хром.